# E2E Encrypting User Data

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I'm building an end-to-end encrypted web-app. I plan to use ECDH + P256 curve for generating private/public keys. The private keys are saved onto the user's computer and the public keys are stored on a server. The recipient's public keys are pulled from the server when the sender wants to encrypt and send a file. The sender uses the public keys to derive a secret. The file is encrypted using AES-GCM and sent over to the recipient.

My questions are:

1. How can this system be improved?
2. I've read it's good practice to rotate keys. Is there a function that allows the new keys to open old encrypted files? Or do those files need to get thrown away?
3. Do public keys need to be encrypted in transit?

Answer (score 3):

The first issue here is how you describe the use of "public" and "private" in terms of Diffie-Hellman. In DH, you don't have a single public and private keypair. Both parties have a public and private keypair, and they both exchange their public keys with each other. From that exchange, they may both agree upon some shared secret.

The next issue that arises comes from that misunderstanding. Two DH keypairs will generate the same shared secret every time you perform a DH key exchange. The process is deterministic. This means that every time you perform a file transfer, the same bulk encryption key is used for that user. This is problematic when you want to encrypt a lot of data (gigabytes of files) because you don't have any key rotation. Your question on key rotation touches on this, but focuses on the wrong target (data at rest).

The most important fault of this scheme is that, while public component of the DH keypair does not need to be *encrypted*, it must be *authenticated*. Your scheme uses what we call "anonymous" Diffie-Hellman, because the DH exchange is not authenticated. This is vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack whereby an attacker gets in the middle of the DH exchange and sends the server their own DH public key instead of the client's. They can then perform a key exchange with you, make another key exchange with the server, and proxy all the data through and access the plaintext.

Another problem is that using long-term DH keypairs alone for key exchange lacks a feature called forward secrecy. Consider what happens if an attacker records all data over the network, passively, then later compromises one of the private keys: they can use the private key to decrypt all the key exchanges that they have recorded. This compromises *all* prior file transfers. The solution to this is to use something called ephemeral key exchange, but it's unclear how this fits into your protocol because of the other issues.

The main question I would ask is: does the server need to be able to decrypt the files, or is it just storing encrypted data that the client can later decrypt?

If the server does *not* need access to the files, you don't need DH. The "standard" scheme for these situations is:

1. Derive an unlock key from somewhere, that only the client knows. This could be from a passphrase with a KDF such as Argon2, or just a random sequence of bytes in a file on the client machine if you don't need or want the user to have to enter a password. Just keep in mind that if the client computer is compromised and you use the latter approach, all the file data can be decrypted.
2. Randomly generate a file key and IV/nonce. Encrypt the file data with AES-GCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305, using the file key.
3. Encrypt the file key and IV/nonce with AES-ECB, using the unlock key. This is one of the few cases where AES-ECB actually makes sense to use, because you know the blocks will be unique and random, and you're never re-using the same key to encrypt the same data.
4. Transfer the encrypted file key and the encrypted data to the server, preferably over HTTPS. You can technically use HTTP because the data is encrypted and an attacker can't decrypt it anyway, but HTTPS provides guarantees about the identity of the server, and also serves as an extra layer of security in case you have an implementation bug somewhere.
5. The server stores this data.
6. When the client wants to decrypt the data, it downloads the encrypted file key and the encrypted data. It then uses the unlock key to decrypted the file key, and uses that to authenticate and decrypt the file data.

Ultimately, this is identical to putting the file in an encrypted zip and uploading it somewhere.

If the server *does* require access to the files, then it's a bit more complicated.

If the server needs to access the plaintext data at any point, even without user presence, then there's no point in encrypting the data on the server. If the server has the keys to decrypt the data, and those keys are stored on the server too, it's like putting the key right next to the padlock. In such a case you should just upload the plaintext file to the server over HTTPS, and have the server store them in plaintext. You can and should use full-disk encryption on the server itself, but if an attacker compromises the server and the server has access to the data, then the data is also compromised. There's no way around that.

If the server only needs access to the plaintext data when the user is present, e.g. during a web request, then you use the same "no server access" scheme as above but give the server the unlock key over HTTPS when needed. The server keeps the unlock key for as long as it needs it, then throws it away. There are variants of this approach for slightly different threat models, but that's a complex topic and not worth discussing until your requirements are clear.

Comment: The server should not be able to view the data. In the standard scheme, how does the recipient get the unlock key if it never leave the sender’s computer?

Comment: Also, the encrypted files (mostly pdfs) could be quite large up to 500MB. Why is this a problem with DH?

Comment: @SoLetsGo DH cannot, itself, encrypt data. It is a shared secret agreement scheme which produces secret of a certain size. This is why you use DH to agree upon a secret and use that secret to encrypt the bulk data with a symmetric algorithm.

Comment: @SoLetsGo It wasn't clear to me that the files needed to be accessed by a third party but not accessible by the server. One solution would just be to have users provide each other with a shared password that is used to decrypt the data, via an out-of-bound channel, although at that point it's again not much different to just emailing or hosting an encrypted zip. A multi-party file encryption scheme with an untrusted coordinator (the server) is much more complex to implement and is likely not achievable without significant work.

Comment: @SoLetsGo Identity management and authenticity are major challenges here. For example, if the server acted as a coordinator node through which users can exchange DH public keys and encrypted file data, doing so over HTTPS would be sufficient enough for each user to prove the identity of the server and therefore prevent MitM attacks by attackers in the network path. This is fairly simple for 2-party exchanges. But the server itself can trivially perform a MitM attack in that scenario, and there's no solution for that unless users can independently authenticate the exchanged keys.

Comment: @SoLetsGo If you try to resolve the key authenticity and identity problem you ultimately end up with something like PGP, whereby each user must publish a public key through some trusted mechanism (usually out-of-band, such as in person or through consensus on independently operated key servers) which can be used to verify the identity of the user via signing - something DH cannot provide. The security of systems like this completely hinges on the ability to cryptographically prove that you are communicating with the right person, and ultimately that means you need a trusted channel somewhere.

Comment: The reason I need E2EE is so the server cannot possibly view the files. Only the intended recipients. If I assume that the server is trustable, would using P-256 + ECDH + AES-GCM  with a key rotation & frequent data deletion be a reasonable approach?

Comment: @SoLetsGo If you assume that the server is trusted then you should just put the data on the server in the clear and upload/download using HTTPS. If you don't want the server to be able to read the data, then you don't consider the server to be trusted. The threat model where you don't trust the server with having access to plaintext data but do trust the server to coordinate the encryption of that data, with the ability to break that encryption, doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @SoLetsGo What you want to do is something that people have been working on for decades without success. It's a fundamental requirement that you need some trusted pre-shared information in order to form a secure channel. You simply cannot have a secure channel without that. With HTTPS this is solved with certificate authorities. With PGP this is solved by exchanging public keys over some trusted channel ahead of time. With SSH it's solved with pubkeys, which clients need to have a copy of in order to verify the identity of the server.

Comment: @SoLetsGo To explain the scenario: Alice and Bob upload their ECDH public keys to the server, and keep their ECDH private keys safely on their computers. Now the server is the authority on what those ECDH keys are. Alice wants to send a file to Bob. Alice requests Bob's public key from the server. Instead of doing that, the server makes up a new ECDH key and sends that. Alice has no way to know that this happened. Alice then uses that to compute a shared secret, and uses that secret to encrypt the file. Alice sends the encrypted file to the server. The server can now decrypt the file.

Comment: @SoLetsGo If you trust the server not to do that, then you must also trust the server with the plaintext data - they're one and the same. If you don't trust the server with the plaintext data, then you need to come up with a concrete security mechanism that prevents the server from being able to carry out that attack. The only way to do that is by giving the users some way of authenticating each other's keys, *without* the server having the opportunity to mess with that process. Which means you need some authority on identity, or a trusted out-of-band channel.

Comment: @SoLetsGo If the trusted out-of-band channel can be used at any time, there's no reason not to just use that to send a password to an encrypted zip and email/share that, instead of a complex cryptographic scheme. If the trusted out-of-band channel can only be used once, ahead of time, then the users can use that to share PGP public keys, which they then use to sign & encrypt files over whatever sharing solution is easiest, e.g. email or Microsoft OneDrive. No need for fancy custom crypto schemes on servers.